How to update Planning Variable fields during solving time in OptaPy
I have a problem where I am assigning teachers to classes. One of the requirements I have is to distribute classes to teachers uniformly. That is, all teachers should take similar number of classes. Therefore, if there are two teachers, 6 classes, then each teacher should  get 3 classes each, even if 5 classes to teacher1 and 1 class to teacher2 is an optimal solution.
In this case, my understanding is, I have to update classCount parameter in Teacher class every time a teacher to class assignment is made, and have a constraint that checks the count while assignment. I'm trying to see how to update the classCount parameter during solving time.
from optapy import problem_fact, planning_id
These are the classes defined
@problem_fact
class `Teacher`:
  

    def __init__(self, id, first_name=None, last_name=Non):
        self.id = id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.class_count = 0

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def get_firstname(self):
        return self.first_name

    def set_firstname(self, first_name):
        self.first_name = first_name

    def get_lastname(self):
        return self.last_name

    def set_lastname(self, last_name):
        self.last_name = last_name


    def add_class(self):
        self.class_count += 1

    def remove_class(self):
        self.class_count -=1

    def get_class_count(self):
        return self.visit_count


@planning_entity
class `Class`:
   

    def __init__(self, id=None, class_name=None,
                 class_type_id=None,
                 timeslot_id=None, duration=None, teacher=None):
        self.id = id
        self.class_name = class_name
        self.class_type_id = class_type_id
        self.timeslot_id = timeslot_id  # class start time
        self.duration = duration
        self.teacher = teacher

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def get_class_name(self):
        return self.class_name

    def set_class_name(self, class_name):
        self.class_name = class_name


    def get_class_type(self):
        return self.class_type_id

    def set_class_type(self, class_type_id):
        self.class_type = class_type_id

    def get_start_time(self):
        return self.timeslot_id

    def set_start_time(self, timeslot_id):
        self.timeslot_id = timeslot_id

    def get_duration(self):
        return self.duration

    def set_duration(self, duration):
        self.duration = duration

    @planning_variable(Teacher, [‘teacherList'])
    def get_teacher(self):
        return self.teacher

    def set_teacher(self, teacher):
         self.teacher = teacher


 @planning_solution
    class `TeacherAssignmentSolution`:
        def __init__(self,
                     … // other variables
                     teacher_timeslot_list,
                     class_type_list,
                     timeslot_list,
                     class_list,
                     score=None
                     ):
                   
             self.teacher_timeslot_list = teacher_timeslot_list
            self.class_type_list = class_type_list
            self.timeslot_list = timeslot_list
            self.class_list = class_list
            self.score = score
    
    
        @problem_fact_collection_property(TeacherTimeSlot)
        def get_teacher_timeslot_list(self):
            return self.teacher_timeslot_list
    
        @problem_fact_collection_property(ClassType)
        def get_class_type_list(self):
            return self.class_type_list
    
        @problem_fact_collection_property(Timeslot)
        def get_timeslot_list(self):
            return self.timeslot_list
    
        @problem_fact_collection_property(Teacher)
        @value_range_provider(‘teacherList')
        def get_teacher_list(self):
            return self.teacher_list
    
        @planning_entity_collection_property(Class)
        def get_class_list(self):
            return self.class_list
    
        @planning_score(HardMediumSoftScore)
        def get_score(self):
            return self.score
    
        def set_score(self, score):
            self.score = score

I am trying to penalize the class count on a teacher so that when the assignment happens the next class is assigned to a teacher who has the least number of classes from the previous solution.
def total_classes_per_teacher(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
"""penalize unequal class assignment"""
return constraint_factory 
.forEach(Class)
.join(Teacher,
Joiners.equal(lambda visit:class.teacher.id,
lambda teacher:teacher.id)
)
.penalize(“teacher with more classes than the other", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
lambda class, teacher : teacher.get_class_count())
I do not know how to achieve this.Looking for an implementation in OptaPy or TimeFold with Python implementation
